# Nativescript command run

Tags: android, nativescript

I have installed `Android-SDK` in my `ARC Linux` system.
but when run command `tns run android`

> The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: set your ANDROID_HOME to an existing sdk directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **ANDROID_HOME** and **PATH** in .profile file in $HOME directory as :

```
export ANDROID_HOME="path/to/android-sdk" export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then try add android as :

```
tns platform add android
```

For any doubt refer here : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1097
This is the original post in NativeScript Github page

Comment: now it showing this although  have installed android-sdk...
`Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.`

Comment: ya, its clear from the message that you have to install Android SDK 22 or later for compiling your project

Comment: No.
Showing same .

Comment: dont you installed android sdk 22 or above ?

Comment: i installed 3 times again and again then also its showing same only .

Comment: Make sure you you have Android SDK Build Tools and Android support repository installed. (You can find it under Extras section in Android SDK Manager)

Comment: after doing the above, run tns doctor and verify if there is error. If no error found, you are good to go.